# Why do I need TaskType in createForm?

Tags: symfony, crud, symfony-3.3

I'm beginner. Yesterday I tested Symfony's tools like generate:doctrine:crud. I see now that many things I can do much easier then manually. The case is after analyzing generated code I found:

```
 $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\TaskType', $task);
```

I spend some time reading official doc and some tutorials but I can't find exact answer for my doubts.
Why do I need this part: `AppBundle\Form\TaskType`?
What should it contain? I see that I can move to TaskType file building the form.

```
$builder->add('name')->add('datetime');
```

But it's not much usefulness if I have to create separated file only for that. Is there way to avoid using TaskType file? I tried to run edit form for Task Entity this way:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm($task);
```

But it goes wrong way.
Regards,
Lukasz

EDIT #1 ----- controller editAction for Task Entity

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing task entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="task_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($task);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\TaskType', $task);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('task_edit', array('id' => $task->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('task/edit.html.twig', array(
        'task' => $task,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

and TaskType

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')->add('datetime');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_task';
    }


}
```

Comment: Post the contents of create form and the full controller, I've not used the same version than you when generating crud and in my case I had a create form method per action

Comment: Code added, version 3.3.10

Comment: Welcome to Symfony.  Your best bet might be to work through some of the [form examples](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) in the docs.  Make sure the doc version number (upper right hand corner) matches your Symfony version.  Once you have a basic understanding of forms then the crud stuff will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method of the controller you are calling.

The Framework Controller is a facade to multiple symfony services. One of them is the FormFactory service.

To create a form you need:

1. The form type (Required)
2. Data (Optional)
3. Form Options (Optional)

CreateForm() it is implemented in the parent class so it is generic for all kind of forms and implementations.

## Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller

```
    /**
     * Creates and returns a Form instance from the type of the form.
     *
     * @param string|FormTypeInterface $type    The built type of the form
     * @param mixed                    $data    The initial data for the form
     * @param array                    $options Options for the form
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    public function createForm($type, $data = null, array $options = array())
    {
        return $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($type, $data, $options);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Where did you find this definition? I found only https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L304 but comments are less usable.

Comment: I'm still on Symfony 2.7 on the project I have open now

Comment: Check the form factory interface: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactoryInterface.php#L32